# Dependent tests in rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, automated-tests

I write functional tests, and I need to do tests that were being would depend on the passage of previous tests. Let's say I have a button that opens a window in which there is a functional. That is, in order to check this functionality, I need to first check the correct operation of the button (ie, open window or not functional). So, I need to do so that would be if the test failed on a button click, the tests did not run to check the functional window. Writing tests separately - for me is not an option. I would like to see something like this:

```
describe "some tests" do
  open_result = nil

  it "should check work button" do
    click_to_button()
    open_result = window_opened?
    open_result.should == true
  end

  if open_result

    describe "Check some functional" do

      it "should check first functional"

      it "should check second functional"

    end

  end

end
```

I know that this method does not work for rspec. It's just a simple description of what I want to see. Is it achievable using rspec? If not, are there other ways (gems, etc.)

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because there is sqa.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

RSpec is designed as a **unit tests** framework, so it may be a little difficult to get perfect functional-test behavior from it. In RSpec's philosophy tests **must** be independent. It is especially important when you use *autotest*: in this case the order of execution is truly unpredictable. Sad but true.

Still, of course you can save some state between test using global (`$a`) <s>or instance (`@a`, not sure here)</s> variables. Anyway you need to move `if` into `it` block so that it will be executed in time. You may use [`pending`](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Pending-Examples) keyword to interrupt a test without failing it in case if pre-condition is not met.

**BUT**

I'm sure that the best solution is to avoid [golden hammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) antipattern, and not to write functional tests in unit-test framework. You want not to test some separate functions. You do want to test **scenarios**. So I suggest trying some scenario-testing suite.

Behold, [**Cucumber**](http://cukes.info/)! Usage is simle:

1. Define parametrized scenario *steps* in Ruby, and expectations in RSpec-style
2. Write scenarios in natural language *(yes, not only English, but even Russian or whatever — the power of Regexps is on your side)*

In your case, you will have in `features/step_definitions/gui_steps.rb` something like

```
Given /I pushed a button "(.*)"/ do |name|
    @buttons.find(name).click() # This line is pseudo-code, you know
end
```

and something similar for checking window opening, etc (see [examples](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/master/examples/i18n/en/features/step_definitons/calculator_steps.rb)). Then you can combine defined steps in any way, for example your two scenarios might look like

```
Scenario: Feature 1
    Given I pushed a button "go"
    And I focus on opened window
    When I trigger "feature 1"
    Then I should se "result 1" in text area

Scenario: Feature 2
    Given I pushed a button "go"
    And I focus on opened window
    When I trigger "feature 2"
    Then I should se "result 2" in text area
```

In both cases, if some step of scenario fails (like *I focus on opened window* — if it is not opened), **the consequent steps are not executed** — just as you want. As a bonus you get an *extremely* detailed output of what happened and on what step (see pics on the site).

The good news is that you don't always need to define all the step yourself. For example, when you test a web app, you can use webrat steps for typical things like *When I go to url/a/b/c* and *Then I should see text "foo" on the page*. I don't know which GUI testing framework you use, but probably there are already steps for it, so I suggest you to google on *Cucumber %framework name%*. Even if not, writing these steps once will not be more difficult than trying to make Cucumber from RSpec.

Comment: As much as we hate to answer a question with "don't do that," Cucumber is a much better hammer for that nail.  Great explanation.

Comment: Other than the language, is that really so different to writing the steps as methods and calling them in sequence from a vanilla rspec test?

Comment: @Frederick, "Other than the language," no, but the language is a huge deal.  Rspec is a DSL for tests.  Cucumber is a meta-DSL for tests: It's a DSL which lets you easily write a DSL specific to what you're testing.  This might seem like a quibble, but it makes a huge difference in how you think about and write tests.

Comment: @FrederickCheung, in short, the main advantages in using Cucumber over calling methods from different RSpec specs are **(1)** readability (and writability) of tests, and **(2)** informativeness and clarity of failure messages. That's because Cucumber is not only a meta-DSL, but also some logic behind it. Might seem not important until you try, but believe me, when one tries it, he no longer wants invent a bicycle while there is one already.

Comment: "using global ($a) or instance (@a..." -- setting @a between examples won't be shared if they are set within examples. However, setting $a is recognized across examples

Comment: @Unglued, ok, I striked out that unsure part.