# How to execute the another it block based on the value in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
a=0

describe "desc-1" do
  it "it-1" do
    puts "IT -1 "
    a=1
  end
  if (a==1) 
    it "it-2" do
      puts "IT-2"
    end
  end
end
```

the second it block must be executed,but now it is not executing can u please help thanks in advance

Comment: Your question lacks some context, what is the code, where is it being called.  is this a test block?  With the context of the code people will be better able to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a scope issue. Local variable values assigned inside the `it` block will not be available outside of that context. In this case, if this is Rspec as it looks, your second example is not getting run because `a` evaluates to `0` in that context, but it *will* evaluate to `1` if you just allow the second block to run and test the expectation. This will work

```
a = 0

describe "a" do    
  it "is 0" do
    expect(a).to eq 0

    a = 1
  end

  it "is 1" do
    expect(a).to eq 1
  end
end
```

However now your second example is dependent on the first example running before it. A better idea would be to define the variable within the block testing the expectation, in which case it's a good idea to change it back afterward with an `after` block so you it resets to the default.

```
a = 0

describe "a" do
  after { a = 0 }

  it "is 0" do
    expect(a).to eq 0
  end

  it "can be changed to 1" do
    a = 1

    expect(a).to eq 1
  end
end
```

Comment: If i remove that expect statement also it works but my requirement is based on the if condition a=1 second block must execute.

Comment: can you describe what you're trying to do and why? is it a test? The way you're trying to run the code the second block won't execute because `a != 1` in that context

Answer (score 0):

In RSpec your `it` blocks should be independent of each other and each test a specific piece of behavior. (Check out [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835283/dependent-tests-in-rspec))

If you need to share a value across examples, assign the variable in a [before(:all)](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#define-before(:all)-block-in-example-group) block, but the order your tests are run should be random to ensure limited side effects ([read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826600/why-does-rails-5-order-test-cases-randomly)) so even this wouldn't really give you your answer.

If you want tests that test a larger system or series of actions look at this [Rails Guide for functional testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#what-to-include-in-your-functional-tests) or this [great article on functional tests](http://culttt.com/2016/03/16/writing-functional-tests-ruby-rails/).